# How many ideals does the ring $\mathbb Z_{12}⊕\mathbb Z_{12}$ have$?$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there any relation between the ideals of $\mathbb Z_{12}$ and $\mathbb Z_{12}\oplus\mathbb Z_{12}$ $?$ Can we also generalize it$?$
Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ideals of a direct sum $A_1\oplus A_2$ are all of the form $I_1\oplus I_2$, where $I_1$ and $I_2$ are ideals of $A_1$ and $A_2$.